# Mock GPS Provider only works while in Debug mode

Tags: android, gps, mocking

I have been updating an app and pulling the version target forward, and we are running into an issue with GPS Mocking.

The mock locations works perfectly when debugging with android studio, but when I leave debugging and just run normally it doesn't work at all.

Background:

This is pulling GPS information over serial and mocking the device's location. This all works right up until the mocking, then the location wont be set unless I am actively debugging.

If I am missing something please let me know, it seems like some security restriction I'm not aware of holding us down.

EDIT: I still can't find anything around this, and it seems specifically when I'm stepping through the code it works, but otherwise just running doesn't work

Comment: are you using physical or emulated device?

Comment: Physical, with mock locations turned on in dev settings

Comment: Show me how you are implementing the code, so we can solve out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if Mock Locations **REQUIRES** debug mode. When creating a "release" build debug mode still had to be declared.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked `[ro.allow.mock.location]` with `getprop | grep mock` over adb shell?

Set it to 1 (`setprop ro.allow.mock.location 1`) it should work on release mode as well. It's initially 0. If that doesn't work please give me a feedback so i can change my answer.